# Multiple APK inside Android Studio Like Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

For some reason I can't find a clear cut answer to this.  I am currently using Eclipse for my Android projects and as you can see from the screenshot my workspace has multiple APK projects, hundreds to be exact.

The reason for doing this is because it is easy to copy and reuse projects within the same workspace very quickly.

My question is, can this setup be done in Android Studio?  I can't tell if it's one APK per Android Studio, or you can work with multiple in the same instance sharing dependencies like Eclipse did.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can do this. File -> New Module -> Phone & Tablet Module or File -> Import Module.

Comment: You have quite a weird way of developing it seems. Android Studio can't do that, primarily because such a way of organizing and reusing your code is not in line with modern programming practices...

Comment: Just did it just fine buddy. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it just fine without any issues.  I was able to set two projects as Android projects in the `settings.gradle` file and just choose which one I want to launch.  Hopefully over 300 of these doesn't start a performance issue.  If it does I will just need to remove the modules and add the correct ones when exporting a new APK.

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':comexposure0', ':comexposure5', 'exposurelibrary'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I am currently using Eclipse for my Android projects and as you can see from the screenshot my workspace has multiple APK projects, hundreds to be exact.

Been there, done that, found it to be unusable, except by keeping most of the projects closed, as it appears that you are doing based on your screenshot.

> The reason for doing this is because it is easy to copy and reuse projects within the same workspace very quickly.

In Android Studio, you copy and reuse projects by coping the directory, using your development OS' file manager, the command line, or your favorite other file-management tool.

> can this setup be done in Android Studio?

Not really. Android Studio supports a project having multiple modules, where those modules can be apps or libraries. There is certainly nothing stopping you from attempting to create a single Android Studio project consisting of hundreds of modules. However, they would all be the equivalent of *open* projects in Eclipse (`actionbarsherlock` and `com.exposure.0` in your screenshot). I would expect Android Studio's performance to be worse than Eclipse's with hundreds of open projects, assuming that Android Studio did not flat-out crash due to running out of memory.

Comment: Appreciate this insight.  Do you think I should do a project per APK then???  You are correct closing the project helped with performance.  There is no way to hide a APK module in Android Studio?

Comment: @MikeFlynn: "Do you think I should do a project per APK then?" -- I would see if there's some other solution. In my case, my hundreds of projects are from [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android), and they all do different things. From your package names, it feels like your apps are much more similar. There may be ways of doing what you need in a single project (e.g., per-customer branding via product flavors). "There is no way to hide a APK module in Android Studio?" -- not that I know of.

Comment: Yes 99% per the same except the branding, all use the same external project, just different icons and launch files and some text updates.

Comment: @MikeFlynn: Most likely, that can be a single Android Studio project, where you use product flavors to override the resources for each brand. You can then build one APK per brand from that single project (through the IDE, through Gradle tasks on the command line, through your CI server, etc.). It'll take some work to convert, but it's a long-term more maintainable option. Starter docs are [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html).

Comment: @MikeFlynn: Probably not, as splits do not solve any problems that you have, AFAIK. Product flavors do.

Comment: I was able to do this just fine with my answer above by just including both Android projects.